# Почему зависает деплой на "Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment..."?

Tags: php, docker, composer, dokku

Есть репозиторий с проектом на CMS OpenCart.

Для него создал следующие файлы:

**.buildpacks:**

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git
```

**composer.json:**

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "chmod -R 777 system/storage/cache/",
      "chmod -R 777 system/storage/download/",
      "chmod -R 777 system/storage/logs/",
      "chmod -R 777 system/storage/modification/",
      "chmod -R 777 system/storage/session/",
      "chmod -R 777 system/storage/upload/",
      "chmod -R 777 system/storage/vendor/",
      "chmod -R 777 image/",
      "chmod -R 777 image/cache/",
      "chmod -R 777 image/catalog/",
      "chmod -R 777 config.php",
      "chmod -R 777 admin/config.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx
```

Делаю коммит. Далее прописываю:

```
git push dokku master
```

И все зависает на этом моменте:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 273 bytes | 136.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building my-app from herokuish...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
```

Почему так происходит? Почему процесс не идет дальше?